# Make periodic task occur every 2 seconds

Tags: windows-phone-8

I need to check regularly if a new message has been received because the API service I am integrating with does not have a push notification service. How do I set how often a periodic task runs for?

I have the boiler plate code (eg. http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/54f4b6/periodic-and-resourceintensive-tasks-in-windows-phone-mango/) from any example on the internet, but it seems it can only run roughly every 30 minutes :() ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately periodic tasks run not more often than 30 minutes and they are not even guaranteed to run. If you want to run more often than that your only bet is setting up a push notification service...